Why template accept a not matching parameter?
code source file in godbolt:
https://godbolt.org/z/1E1oEsdKW

template <typename T>
concept C1 = sizeof(T) != sizeof(int);

template <template <C1 T> class X>
struct S4
{
    X<int> x;
};

template <typename T>
class Test
{
  public:
    T t;
};

int main()
{
    S4<Test> s1;  
    return 0;
}

S4 expects a template template argument whose type argument is restricted by the concept C1.
But still I can instantiate S4 with X, even though X<int> should break the concept (sizeof(int) is not different from sizeof(int)).
gcc and clang compile it without errrors, while mscv complains:
error C3201: the template parameter list for class template 'Test' does not match the template parameter list for template parameter 'X'x64 msvc v19.40 VS17.10 #Executor 1

This is what I would expect, because Ts argument is constraint by the concept while Test has no such constraint.

It's kinda a surprise for me that concept can be applied in that context. I was always under impression these types are for reference only

While I do get an error (as shown here) it's a completely different one.

please do not remove the error message from the question. It is important to understand the question. And please only one question per question

I don't know what the standard says about this, but if you consider class templates as functors, meaning maps A -> X where X is the set of all types and A is a subset of X, and concepts basically are subset of X as well, then X4 expects a map C1 -> X as its argument. Test is a map X -> X, which can naturally be constrained to a map C1 -> X, by only admitting arguments from C1. So it would be natural to treat Test as that constrained map in this context.

@chrysante but one can see it the opposite way as well. Suppose S4 takes a template argument X and a type T and wants to check if X<T> can be instantiated. gcc would give the wrong answer.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai sorry, it seems I didn't read the question correctly

This is about the rules of Template Template Parameters:
Parameter List of the Parameter Template: The parameter list of the called template must match the parameter list of the parameter template.
Comparison of Constraints:

Constraints of the Parameter Template (i.e., P in S) must be equally strict or less strict than the constraints of the argument templates (X, Y, Z).
Argument Templates cannot require more constraints than the parameter template

Example:
template<typename T> concept C = requires (T t) { t.f(); };
template<typename T> concept D = C<T> && requires (T t) { t.g(); };
template<typename T> concept E = D<T> && requires (T t){t.h();};

template<template<D> class P> struct S { };

template<C> struct X { };
template<D> struct Y { };
template<typename T> struct Z { };

S<X> s1;            // OK, X have more loose constraints
S<Y> s2;            // OK, Y and P have equivalent constraints
S<Z> s3;            
S<E> s4;            // error, E is stricter than D


int main()
{
    return 0;
}


In godbolt:
https://godbolt.org/z/xW33aEfzT
reference src:
https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg.template

this is the necessary context but what is the answer?

constraints of X in S4 are not equally or less strict than those of T in Test, hence msvc is right and the others are wrong. Correct?

and you should give a proper reference for content quoted from elsewhere

@463035818_is_not_an_ai: the other side, X<anyTypeSastifyingC1> should pass, other might pass too,

So clang, gcc and any other compiler that compiles that code fine has a bug, right ?

Maybe, that defined by how there compilers deal with the X

Your answer should have a concluding paragraph where the principles are applied to the specific case of S4<Test>.
